# Digital Metaphors Report Builder 11.05: why my DELPHI code crashes without any error?

Tags: reportbuilder

Now I build a template for our invoice printer.
But I do really not know, why it crashes without any error.

My goal is to separate the String ItemName at the ';' and print each part into a new line to a Memo1.

```
procedure DetailBeforeGenerate;
var
  s1: String;
  s2: String;
  wordcount: Integer;
  notelength: Integer;

begin
 s1 := plPrintInvLine['ItemName'];
 notelength := Length(s1);
while notelength > 0 do
begin
    notelength := Length(s1);
    wordcount := Pos(';' , s1);
    s2 :=   Copy(s1, 0, wordcount-1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s2);
    Delete(s1, 0, wordcount);
end;

end;
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it? What is `plPrintInvLine`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -  I use ReportBuilder - I think he is in their runtime environment which isn't really Delphi - it's a Pascal scripting language that executes at runtime when you render  a report. There's no straightforward way to trace through in the debugger.

Comment: @Rudolph If this code is not Delphi, then please tag it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments below regarding accessing index[0] in a string and thanks to David Heffernen and Ken White. **BUT**:

Looks like you've got an infinite loop in your code:

```
notelength := Length(s1);
while notelength > 0 do
begin
    notelength := Length(s1);
    wordcount := Pos(';' , s1);
    s2 :=   Copy(s1, 0, wordcount-1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s2);
    Delete(s1, 0, wordcount);
end;
```

***Delete(s1, 0, wordcount);*** Has no effect! Try it in Delphi debugger. Result? notelength is never decremented so you'll loop forever. ' Delete(s1, 0, wordcount);' does not blow up but neither does it delete. Use **Delete(s1,1, wordcount)** instead.

Index[0] in Delphi strings does not contain your character data - it's 'not accessible' according to the compiler, if you try compiling myString[0];

Also: the way your code is written, you MUST terminate with ';' or a string such as this:

**s1 := 'mikey;was;here;a';** will loop infinitely on the last string after ';' ('a')

I also use ReportBuilder templates, etc: In Delphi itself you will not be able to compile MyString[0], but the copy and delete methods are protected from this error, (as David explained) however it appears from what I saw in the debugger that 'Delete(s1, 0, wordcount)' will not throw an exception but fails to delete. So I would not expect RBuilder to be any better, and perhaps worse - copy() may also be failing on string[0] in RAP.

RAP is **NOT** Delphi - it is a Runtime scripting environment that runs in your template, based on Object Pascal, but it does not support everything, and you cannot always expect it to behave exactly like Delphi.

BTW - ReportBuilder is now up to version 14.0X - if possible you should upgrade - there have been a lot of improvements in the RAP environment. In a later version your code might work OK or you'll get back an error message from RAP.

Also: If you want to debug in RAP it's not so easy. But to give you a clue as to where the error might be occurring, put a text label on your report and after each line of your code add

```
mylabel.caption:='statementxxx ran';
```

or

```
mylabel.caption:= myVariable.value;
```

Etc. That will give you a little ad hoc tracer  - maybe show you where/why you failed, etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - see new answer. Try it in debugger. (I used Delphi 7...)

Comment: Just a slight correction: `Index[0]` in a Delphi `string` does not exist. It's not "reserved" - it simply does not exist. `string` in Delphi is 1-based, whether `AnsiString`, `UnicodeString`, or a plain old `string` declaration. `ShortString` (or `string[CharLength]`) as a zero index; they're for backward-compatibility with Delphi 1 and pre-Delphi Pascal.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ken. I haven't paid much attention to all the evolutions, because since Delphi 1 and the old pchar days I just always start at [1] and consider [0] off limits - so string[0] in the OP's question jumped out at me. BUT: when I ran some tests using plain vanilla string and ansiString in Delphi 7 it looked like s2:=copy(s1,0,n) worked correctly (the 0 got bumped to 1) but delete(s1,0,n) did nothing - no error and no deletion - as explained in my answer. So it appears that something is not quite consistent. However string[0] will not compile at all: 'Element[0] inaccessible'.

Comment: I see, i was tought just rubbish. They told me, if i don't know sth. i should check google for a delphi tutorial... useless then. The next problem is: we can't upgrade, cause this tool is bought in this version and integrated in our software. A upgrade is not possible. But i have to say: thank you very much! I am testing atm: `s2 :=   Copy(s1, 1, wordcount-1);
 Delete(s1, 1, wordcount);`

Comment: The problem could be, that `wordcount := Pos(';' , s1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('wordcount= ' + IntToStr(wordcount));` always returns 0...

Comment: @RudolphKoch - You should be able to upgrade, but you would have to rebuild your application using the new version. Your version is very old - perhaps something will break if you upgrade. Their tech support is excellent. If it's impossible for you to rebuild/redistribute your application, then you're stuck. But if you can, contact their tech support @ support@DigitalMetaphors.com and ask them about potential problems with an upgrade from 11.X to 14.X . I have used their support many times - always excellent.

Answer (score 1):

For all searching people: I found the solution with the excellent help of this community!

The working code looks like this:

```
    procedure DetailBeforeGenerate;
var
  S1: String;
  S2: String;
  wordcount: Integer;
  notelength: Integer;

begin
 S1 := plPrintInvLine['ArtName'];
 notelength := Length(S1);
while (notelength > 0) do
begin
    wordcount := Pos(';',S1);
    S2 :=   Copy(S1, 1, wordcount-1);
    if ( Pos(' ',S2) = 1 ) then Delete(S2, 1, 1);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S2);
    Delete(S1, 1, wordcount);
    notelength := notelength - wordcount;
end;

end;
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain how this code differs from the first one and what's the problem and/or the solution you found.